# 3d printer set up

Tags: printer-building, creality-ender-3

I am not very used to 3D printers and I just bought my first 3D printer today (Creality3D Ender 3). But I am unable to assemble it. The 3D printer doesn't contain instruction on how to built it which I found very weird. I searched a couple of things on the Internet and I found this website, but after some steps I couldn't read it , I didn't understand what I was reading.

Comment: What printer did you buy? Usually, the build instructions in kits are on the Micro-SD card in the parcel, if you buy a Chinese printer.

Comment: I have never linked to a Google link as this is considered very impolite, but such instructions are very easy to find, you can get them from the manufacturer website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website you looked at is for an entirely different printer and in general.

**Your instructions are in a PDF file on the mini-SD card that came with the printer.** The official Ender 3 support site is https://creality3d.cn/download/produktdatei_c0002 and it also contains the Official Assembly Instructions (to me, the lower right corner). An alternate setup instruction is in [a PDF distributed by Sain Smart](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/D1N3oS2crrS.pdf).